# How to make auto-start on Mac?

Tags: mac, installation

I have installed Apache and mySQL on my Mac and I would like to know how to make these services to auto-start after system boots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preferred way to launch things like that is now launchd -- create a launchd .plist file and put it in /Library/LaunchDaemons.  Apple's documentation is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html).  One warning: launchd items should *not* daemonize themselves.  Apache does this by default, so run it with the `-D FOREGROUND` option.  You can use the file /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist (which is set to start Apple's version of Apache) as an example, just be sure to change the "Label" string so launchd doesn't get yours confused with Apple's.  Create another for mysql, and you're set.  They'll be loaded automatically when the computer boots, or you can load them manually with:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/whatever.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

Create scripts and drop them in /Library/StartupItems?